# EnsureUIThread equivalent in Xamarin.Android (Mono for Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android

I've found a chain of methods in an Android app where `RunOnUiThread` is used to call other methods that also wrap their contents in `RunOnUiThread`. I would like to bake in the assumption that the method will only be called from another method that acquired the UI thread already and throw an exception when that condition isn't met. Xamarin.iOS exposes [`UIApplication.EnsureUIThread`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread%28%29), which handles this nicely.

Is there an equivalent to the Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch) `UIApplication.EnsureUIThread` in Xamarin.Android with similar behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I found on the [Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2400/android-ui-threading) a post by Jonathan Pryor that says the following property:

```
SynchronizationContext.Current
```

is only non-null on the UI thread.  Thus you could write a custom method that can check that property for null.  Then throw an exception as desired.